# How to add a snapshot schedule to GCP boot_disk via terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, disk, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to add snapshot schedule to the boot disk of the vm_instance.

```
provider "google" {
  project = "xxxxxx"
}
resource "google_compute_instance" "xxxxxx" {
  name         = "xxxxxx"
  machine_type = "xxxxxx"
  zone         = "xxxxxx"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "???"
    }
  }
  metadata_startup_script = ";;"
  network_interface {
    network = "default"
   }
}
```

I know how to add a schedule to an external disk:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_disk_resource_policy_attachment

But how do you do this with the vm_instance disk ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a snapshot scheduler on a boot disk, modify the value of “*disk*” field in “*google_compute_disk_resource_policy_attachment*” resource so that it points to the boot disk as it has the same name as the VM name and a “Standard Persistent disk” type by default.
So using the name of the VM created  i.e., “*google_compute_instance.< reference-name >.name*”  will allow you to point the snapshot scheduler to the boot disk of the VM.

[Argument Reference](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#argument-reference) for more information.

Refer to the sample configuration below:

Sample.tf

```
resource "google_compute_disk_resource_policy_attachment" "attachment" {
  name = google_compute_resource_policy.policy.name
  disk = google_compute_instance.<reference-name>.name
  zone = "<zone-name>"
}
```

Reference: [google_compute_disk_resource_policy_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#argument-reference)